# Is there any way to make table's body scrollable without using "display: block" parameter?

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll

I have a problem with displaying my scrollable table. I want to scroll only table's body without header. When I set  "display: block" parameter it misaligns table and it does not look such good as withot this parameter. But when I delete "display: block" then the possibility of scrolling disappear. Do you know any other ways to make tables scrollable? Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: When using a table you must not touche the display property of any of the table's elements, now what you want to achieve can't be done with plain table, you'd need to wrap the table with a scroll able element `overflow:scroll` and make the header a separate element with position sticky within the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

You may use instead a wrapper and `position:sticky`, this way the table-layout algorythm works for the whole table and every columns and rows remain perfectly aligned.

Classic usage in the snippet below :

```css
.myTableWrapper {
width:min-content;/* wraps onto table's width */
height: 100px;
overflow-y:auto;
padding-right:1.3em;
}
thead {
background:white;
position:sticky;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myTableWrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>TH</th><th>TH</th><th>TH</th><th>TH</th><th>TH</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
      <tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

or you can play with `display:grid` and `display:content`s to avoid a wrapper and switvh from a table-layou to a grd model .

resizeable live  example with sticky headers => https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abboqbR , but `display:contents` is not understood yet everywhere .